# how to use git hook to validate commit message according to its template

Tags: git, git-commit, githooks

I am trying to use **git hook** to validate the commit messages of my team.
Its purpose is to ensure a standard for commit messages within my team so that I can generate a change log / release notes based on the commits.

I've configured the global template:

`git.exe config --global commit.template .git/.gitmessage`

Now I would like to create the *pre-commit* hook to ensure that the developers write a commmit message according to the template:

```
types: fix, feat, refactor, style, BREAKING CHANGE

<type>: <description>

[optional body]

[optional footer(s)]
```

If the footer contains `(template-ignore)`, the hook should accept any commit message.
Further, the hook should accept any auto generated commit for branch merges.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking here. How have you tried solving this yourself? Show us your code and explain specifically where you're having trouble.

Comment: I recommend reading about the `prepare-commit-msg` and `commit-msg` hooks.

Comment: I would bet that there are scripts to check for this kind of thing. If so you can move that script into the hooks directory. EDIT: [this](https://github.com/compilerla/conventional-pre-commit) repo looks promising

Answer (score 2):

Using a `pre-commit` or `commit-msg` hook to validate commit messages for a shared team is not the right tool.  Most Git hooks are run on the developer system, which means they can be bypassed, and it's often as easy as doing `--no-verify`.  This leaves no trace and can't be disabled, which is why [the Git FAQ recommends against it](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#restrict-with-hooks).  In addition, forcing these kinds of hooks on users prevents users from doing useful things like creating fixup or squash commits or temporarily saving in-progress work.  These hooks can be valuable for users who wish to use them, but they're not an effective control and shouldn't be forced on users.

It should also be noted that Git does not have a way to automatically install hooks on a user system, because that's a security risk.  Therefore, you couldn't force the installation of the hooks even if you included them in the repository.

If you want to verify commit messages, I'd recommend doing so in a `pre-receive` hook or a CI system on the server side.  That is a place you can create an effective control and verify things.  I'd also recommend including changelog entries as a trailer rather than in the commit summary, since the commit summary should often explain a change relevant to a developer, which is often not the change that's relevant to an end user.  This is what we did at a previous employer, and it worked out pretty well.

So, with that in mind, you can do something like this with a `Changelog` trailer (replace `BASE` and `HEAD` with suitable commits in your CI system):

```
git rev-list --format=%B BASE...HEAD | ruby -ropen3 -e '
    def process(msg, commit)
        out, st = Open3.capture2("git", "interpret-trailers", "--parse", stdin_data: msg, binmode: true)
        raise "git failed" unless st.success?
        saw_changelog = false
        out.each_line do |line|
            if line =~ /^Changelog: (.*)$/
                saw_changelog = true
                body = $1
                if body == "none"
                    $stderr.puts "No changelog entry for #{commit}: ok"
                elsif body =~ /^(fix|feat|refactor|style|BREAKING CHANGE): (.+)$/
                    $stderr.puts "Changelog entry passed for #{commit}: type #{$1}"
                end
            end
        end
        raise "No changelog for #{commit}"
    end
    data = nil
    commit = nil
    while line = gets
        if line =~ /^commit ([0-9a-f]+)$/
            process(data, commit) unless data.nil?
            commit = $1
            data = ""
        else
            data << line
        end
    end
    process(data, commit)
'
```

If you really want to do the commit summary version (instead of the trailer), then you don't need the `git interpret-trailers` invocation and can instead process just the first line.  How to do that is left as an exercise for the reader.